# AVAudioEngine setManualRenderingInputPCMFormat does not work in iOS 11

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioengine

AVAudioEngine supports manual rendering in iOS 11, however the inputBlock never be called in real-time mode, any tips ?

```
self.audioEngine.stop()

try! self.audioEngine.enableManualRenderingMode(.realtime, format: self.audioFormat, maximumFrameCount: 1024)

self.audioEngine.connect(self.audioEngine.inputNode, to: self.audioEngine.mainMixerNode, format: nil)

self.audioEngine.connect(self.audioEngine.mainMixerNode, to: self.audioEngine.outputNode, format: nil)

let result = self.audioEngine.inputNode.setManualRenderingInputPCMFormat(self.audioEngine.manualRenderingFormat, inputBlock: { (frameCount) -> UnsafePointer<AudioBufferList>? in

    print("in inputBlock")

    return nil

})

print(result) // always be true

try! self.audioEngine.start()
```

Comment: I'm on the same problem. According to the WWDC2017 talk, it seems that we have to repeatedly call `engine.manualRenderingBlock`, but it doesn't say where exactly I should call it except "the realtime context". This is really counter-intuitive because AVAudioEngine is something that should take care of calling the render functions appropriately, and I'm suspecting that the implementation of real-time manual rendering in iOS 11 SDK is not really in a finished shape.

Comment: it seems needs to using in c/c++ scope, something like AUGraph, however I don't know how to use it without more documents

Comment: I've found a source code from twilio who have use AVAudioEngine in realtime mode
https://github.com/twilio/video-quickstart-swift/blob/d09b04d0cb31ad8513c894f38843ea0b906a4220/AudioDeviceExample/AudioDevices/ExampleAVAudioEngineDevice.m